# $ being undefined in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I was copying the code from this website http://codepen.io/githiro/pen/ICfFE to use for my website and i've got an error.  The very first function starts with $, `$(function(){` however when I put this through and open it up on google it gets an error saying $ is undefined. I should also point out that I have called the jquery.

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-2.2.2.js"></script>
    <title> What Instrument are you? </title>
</head>
```

How would I fix this? 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: look into the settings/javascript section, you should see all the dependencies required for running this example.

Comment: Note that your `script.js` (which I assume is where your code lives) is included *before* jQuery. You'll want to reverse that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add jQuery to your page before your main script body.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> open it up on google it gets an error saying $ is undefined

This generally means that your jQuery reference is missing. Ensure that you include it prior to the `<script>` tag that contains your jQuery code :

```
<!-- Example CDN Reference to jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
         // Your code here
    });
</script>
```

Comment: <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery-2.2.2.js"></script>
  <title> What Instrument are you? </title>
 </head>
That's what I have. The javascript is running out of the html

Comment: Make sure that you include your jQuery reference **prior** to your `script.js` file if it contains any jQuery code (i.e. `$(function{ ... });`). You'll want to also ensure that your reference is correct and doesn't throw any errors within the Console (i.e. indicating that it was loaded correctly).

Comment: Oh. I see thanks!!